# I want to return a user with a list of all the people they have referred

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am developing a referral system in my software. I have gotten the referral right but I want to list all users that have referred someone with the count of people they referred in the admin end.

Here is my user model

```
public function referrals()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Referral::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}

public function referrer()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Referral::class, 'referred_by', 'id');
}
```

Note: `referred_by` is the person that has referred someone and user_id is the person referred

Here is my referral model

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'referred_by', 'status'];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Here is my referrals migration

```
Schema::create('referrals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->integer('referred_by')->unsigned()->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->string('status')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `has('relationshipName')` which limits your results based on the existence of a relationship in your case *users that have referred some*.

and `withCount('relationshipName')` which will count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them.

```
User::has('referrals')->withCount('referrals')->get()
```

Comment: thanks, mate, this helps a lot but after implementing it I ran into another issue which is that on the referral table there is status column which can be active or null based on same conditions I have set, now after getting all total referral count of a user I want to be able to get the count of dose that is set active and count of those that are not

Comment: you can add a condition to the loaded `withCount()` like this: `:withCount(['referrals' => function (Builder $query) {$query->where('status','active');
}])`

Comment: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given, called in    this is the error i got

Comment: You imported the wrong builder, either import `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;` or just remove `Builder` from  `function (Builder $query)` it should work then.